# SoundCloud HTML5 widget not skipping to high track numbers

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to load the HTML5 SoundCloud widget and immediately start playing track 30 from a set.

My code looks like:

```
<iframe id="sc-widget" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/drasla&start_track=30&auto_play=true></iframe>
```

However, this starts only playing track #25.  The widget seems to paginate the data and only pulls the first 25 tracks at first unless the user scrolls down.

I have tried passing a `limit=100` parameter into the URL, but this doesn't seem to increase the initial load.

Is there anyway to immediately skip to a track after #25 using the widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a playlist for the artist, add tracks, then setup your widget code:

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/<playlist_number>?start_track=<track_number>&auto_play=true
```

example: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/462496?start_track=38&auto_play=true

You'll notice the player jumps directly to track #38 in the example.

Comment: I wound up writing a small script to automatically generate a playlist via the API that contains all an artist's tracks.  Your suggestion works fine with playlists.